# Detect Connected Standby Sleep without Win8 Specific API

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8

Hopefully the answer to this isn't just "not possible", but it may be.

I have a program that supports Windows Vista and above that monitors the WM_POWERBROADCAST message for PBT_APMSUSPEND. When it gets this message it means that the computer is going into sleep mode, so it quickly does some things and pauses itself and then resumes once it gets a PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND message.

This doesn't seem work on windows 8 machines that use the [connected standby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn481238(v=vs.85).aspx) feature. According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848040(v=vs.85).aspx), when connected standby is enabled you need to opt in to receiving the WM_POWERBROADCAST messages. It then links to [the RegisterSuspendResumeNotification function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj613321(v=vs.85).aspx) to use to register for this message.

The problem is, RegisterSuspendResumeNotification seems to require Win 8+. I would really like a way to have one program support vista and above still, and would rather not have to make a windows 8 version, and an "everything else" version. Does anyone know if there's some other API that does a similar thing? Or perhaps if there's some other clever way to get that the computer is entering connected standby without getting the WM_POWERBROADCAST message?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could always use the 'standard' trick of checking if a function is available. Namely, use `HMODULE user32Mod = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");` followed by `FARPROC tgtProc = GetProcAddress(user32Mod, "RegisterSuspendResumeNotification");` (dont forget to call FreeLibrary afterwards) - if the tgtProc == NULL then the function wasn't found and by extension, neither was win8. You can then use this to selectively use one window function or another, when registering the main window's class or when using DialogBox.

Comment: @enhzflep: Why not add that as an answer? :)